# ngx-translate - Cannot isolate translate in library module

Tags: angular, typescript, translate, ngx-translate

I'm trying to build an Angular library that will have a separate set of translations from the consuming module. It consists of multiple modules that are exported to the consumer later via `SharedModule`.

Translation stays in standalone module:

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { InjectionToken, ModuleWithProviders, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { TranslatePoHttpLoader } from '@biesbjerg/ngx-translate-po-http-loader';
import {
  MissingTranslationHandler,
  TranslateLoader,
  TranslateModule as NgxTranslateModule,
} from '@ngx-translate/core';

import { TranslationConfig } from '../models/module-config.model';

export function HttpLoaderFactory(http: HttpClient, config: TranslationConfig) {
  const prefix = config && config.urlPrefix || '/i18n/apps/maps';
  const suffix = config && config.urlSuffix || '.po';

  console.log('Will build new loader');

  return new TranslatePoHttpLoader(http, prefix, suffix);
}

export class CustomMissingTranslationHandler implements MissingTranslationHandler {
  handle(params: MissingTranslationHandlerParams) {
   return params.translateService.parser.interpolate(params.key, params.interpolateParams);
  }
}

export const TRANSLATIONS_CONFIG = new InjectionToken('TRANSLATIONS_CONFIG');

@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [
    NgxTranslateModule,
  ],
  exports: [
    NgxTranslateModule,
  ]
})
export class TranslateModule {
  public static forRoot(config: TranslationConfig): ModuleWithProviders {
    return {
      ngModule: TranslateModule,
      providers: [
        {
          provide: TRANSLATIONS_CONFIG,
          useValue: config
        },
        ...NgxTranslateModule.forChild({
          loader: {
            provide: TranslateLoader,
            useFactory: HttpLoaderFactory,
            deps: [HttpClient, TRANSLATIONS_CONFIG]
          },
          missingTranslationHandler: {
            provide: MissingTranslationHandler,
            useClass: CustomMissingTranslationHandler,
            deps: [TRANSLATIONS_CONFIG],
          },
          isolate: true,
        }).providers
      ],
    };
  }
}
```

Translate module is exposed via `SharedModule`:

```
import { HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { InjectionToken, ModuleWithProviders, NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { ModuleConfigModel } from './models/module-config.model';
import { TranslateModule } from './modules/translate.module';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
   /* ... */
  ],
  imports: [
    TranslateModule,
  ],
  exports: [
    /* ... */
    NgxTranslateModule,
    TranslateModule,
  ]
})
export class SharedModule {
  static forRoot(moduleConfig: ModuleConfigModel): ModuleWithProviders {
    return {
      ngModule: SharedModule,
      providers: [
        {
          provide: ModuleConfigModel,
          useValue: moduleConfig
        },
```

...TranslateModule.forRoot(moduleConfig.translationConfig).providers,
          ]
        };
      }
    }

And `SharedModule` is exposed via `public_api.ts` to consumers. I'm using it like that:

```
imports: [
    SharedModule.forRoot({
      apiKey: environment.apiKey,
      baseURL: environment.urlPrefix,
      translationConfig,
    }),
    TranslateModule.forRoot({
      isolate: true,
    }),
  ],
```

I tried all the combinations of `isolate` in `forChild` method of my module and always main `forRoot()` overrides module initialization from original library `TranslateModule`. The only way that seemed to work was switching to `NgxTranslateModule.forRoot()` in the library file and removing main `NgxTranslateModule.forRoot()` from the library consumer which is totally unacceptable...

TL;DR: translations work as expected when they are not isolated. When I isolate them into lazy loaded `forChild`, they get overridden by main `forRoot()` module initialization. `isolate` flag does not help.

Comment: did you find a solution?

Comment: I wrote a custom translate loader that merges multiple translation files in a format we use (highly specific solution, but works for us). Unluckily, `ngx-translate` is bugged in that aspect and without custom file loaders, it's impossible to handle multiple files with language syncing.